# sonar-redmine plugin in SonarQube 5.6.5

Tags: sonarqube, integration, redmine

Now my sonarQube version is sonar-5.6.5 and I want to use sonar-redmine plugin.

but this plugin was deprecated in my version.

How can i use this plugin in my version?

What plugin is a substituable sonar-redmine plugin?

I want to integrate SonarQube and redmine.

Answer (score 0):

The extensions points used by the SonarQube Redmine plugin are no longer supported in SonarQube 5.6 LTS. This is why this plugin is deprecated.

For your information, you won't find any replacement for this kind of plugin. If you want to better understand why this feature has been removed from SonarQube extension points, please read the ["Stop planning; fix the leak!"](https://blog.sonarsource.com/stop-planning-fix-the-leak/) blog post that I wrote on this topic - in which you can replace "JIRA" by "Redmine".